# Display all results in div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a foreach loop that goes through all possible results of an API query

```
json.results.forEach(function(result) {
     console.log(result.original_title);
     document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText = result.original_title;
}, this);
```

The *console.log* outputs all the elements correctly, however as expected, when I write to the *possible results* div, it only displays the last result.

How can I write my results to a div sequentially, so they are not overwritten, preferably without CSS?

Comment: You are picking element by ID, it will pick same element each time and update its content, therefore you see only the last element in the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText = result.original_title;` to `document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText += result.original_title;` The first option replaces the current content of the div, that's why you only see the last result. The second one appends it to the end, keeping every result.

Answer (score 0):

add all content after it is written in a variable.

```
var content;
json.results.forEach(function(result) {
       console.log(result.original_title);
       content += result.original_title;
}, this);

        document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText = content;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText = result.original_title;
```

every next iteration will overwrite the text inserted by previous one.

Try with

```
json.results.forEach(function(result) {
     console.log(result.original_title);
     document.getElementById("possibleResults").innerText += result.original_title

}, this);
```